# How do I check for an existing user in Rspec on a Post#Create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec3

I am trying to write a test for my `InvitationsController#Create`.

This is a `POST` http action.

Basically what should happen is, once the `post#create` is first executed, the first thing that needs to do is we need to check to see if an `User` exists in the system for the email passed in via `params[:email]` on the `Post` request.

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how I do this.

I will refactor later, but first I want to get the test functionality working.

This is what I have:

```
describe 'POST #create' do
    context 'when invited user IS an existing user' do
        before :each do
          @users =  [
            attributes_for(:user),
            attributes_for(:user),
            attributes_for(:user)
          ]
        end

        it 'correctly finds User record of invited user' do

          expect {
            post :create, invitation: attributes_for(:member, email: @users.first.email)
          }.to include(@users.first[:email])
        end
    end
end
```

This is the error I get:

```
1) Users::InvitationsController POST #create when invited user IS an existing user correctly finds User record of invited user
     Failure/Error: expect {
       You must pass an argument rather than a block to use the provided matcher (include "valentin@parisian.org"), or the matcher must implement `supports_block_expectations?`.
     # ./spec/controllers/users/invitations_controller_spec.rb:17:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I am not surprised by the error, because the Test doesn't feel right to me. I just can't quite figure out how to test for this without writing code in my `controller#action`.

I am using FactoryGirl and it works perfectly, in the sense that it returns valid data for all the data-types. The issue here is how do I get RSpec to actually test for the functionality I need.

Comment: What is the `create` action supposed to do when the email is found? It returns the email as plain text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting is a syntax error, nothing related to whatever your action is supposed to do.
The code you have there it is being interpreted as you are passing a block (`{}`) to the expect method.

I'd change it to something like

```
it 'correctly finds User record of invited user' do
  post :create, { email: @users.first[:email] }
  expect(response).to include(@users.first[:email])
end
```

Assuming that the response of the create action returns the email as plain text, which seems weird to me.

Also note that I have `email` directly passed to the post since you mentioned you were expecting it in `params[:email]` but by the test you wrote seems like you were expecting it in `params[:invitation][:email]`. 
Change that part if that is the case.

Comment: Ok so now the error I am getting is this: `Failure/Error: post :create, { email: @users.first.email }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method 'email' for #<Hash:0x007fbbf9351418>`

Ideas?

Comment: Ah, my bad. It should be `@users.first[:email]` instead of `.email` didn't notice it was a hash. Will edit my answer.

Comment: Figured that would be it, but now I am getting this: `NoMethodError:
       undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass` and there is no line number or anything that is relevant.

Comment: `name`? I guess that is inside the `create` action since you didn't post anything that shows a `name` accessor. Do you mind adding the code of your `create` action?

Comment: That's the weird thing, there is nothing about `name` in my `create` action either. The create action is a bit heavy, and I know you will get overwhelmed...but I am not seeing anything there. Ok I will figure this out. You helped me get this far. Thanks!

Comment: Actually....I just commented out all the code in my `create` action and re-ran the test and I am still getting that strange error.

Comment: By the way, not sure if it matters but I am seeing an error in Devise, that's the only place this error is pointing: `#@myapp/gems/devise-3.2.4/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:22:in 'resource_name'
     # @myapp/gems/devise_invitable-1.3.6/lib/devise_invitable/controllers/helpers.rb:18:in 'authenticate_inviter!'
     # @myapp/gems/devise_invitable-1.3.6/app/controllers/devise/invitations_controller.rb:67:in 'current_inviter'
     # @myapp/gems/devise_invitable-1.3.6/app/controllers/devise/invitations_controller.rb:71:in 'has_invitations_left?'`

Comment: Do you have a name attribute on your user at all? If you try adding a method `name` that returns any string just to see if the devise error goes away.

Comment: On my `User` model, I have this `name` method: `def name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end` But that's not a column on my model.